# How to use multiple ip addresses on one subdomain?

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing, subdomain

I have multiple FTP servers, which users can connect and upload files.

Because I always add more servers and sometimes the servers get full, I want to have a subdomain `ftp.mysite.com`, that will point to one of the available servers.

For example, if I have the following servers:

```
111.111.111.111
222.222.222.222
123.123.123.123
```

And then my server `111.111.111.111` gets full, then I want to remove it from the list (manually or w/e) and then the subdomain will not point to that server anymore.

How can I do that?

Comment: People only upload files to your servers? Because if they download also, then they won't see the same thing when they reconnect. If they only upload, then you can make sure servers never get full by moving uploaded things away. You may want to investigate clustered storage that can make storage on several servers seem like one single storage area available on all the servers.

Answer (score 3):

This is round robin DNS. This is a quite simple solution for load balancing. Usually DNS servers rotate/shuffle the DNS records for each incoming DNS request. Unfortunately it's not a real solution for fail-over. If one of the servers fail, some visitors will still be directed to this failed server.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest running a "dynamic dns" service - for example dyn.com (there are plenty of them), setting the TTL value for the DNS address to some small value like 60 or 20 seconds, and running a watchdog service that will change the DNS record via dynamic dns service API as soon as you detect that the server is getting full. This will require writing some code to actually monitor server states and make API calls to DNS provider though.